# Implications of merge method in AggregateFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to understand the AggregateFunction in Flink which is described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#aggregatefunction). Totally it has four methods namely,

1. createAccumulator
2. add
3. getResult
4. merge

From my understanding,

`createAccumulator` method is invoked when the first element enters into a new window and newly created instance will be used further

`add` method is invoked to reduce the result based on definition and this uses the instance which is created in `createAccumulator` method

`getResult` method is invoked when a window is closed and returns the available result

Whether my understanding about the above methods are correct or not? Finally, what is the use-case of `merge` method and when it is used/invoked? The definition available [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/AggregateFunction.html) is not clear for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `merge` method is called when two windows are merged. This applies to session windows, which are merged whenever two sessions are collapsed into one by the arrival of an event that bridges the gap between the sessions. When this occurs, the aggregated results-to-date of both sessions are combined by calling `merge`.

Comment: Makes sense now. I am not able to find this important information in any of the documentation.