# merge() method on AggregateFunction in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I want to know when the `merge()` method on `AggregateFunction` gets called. From what I've understood from the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65848095/implications-of-merge-method-in-aggregatefunction) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284901/aggregatefunction-with-sessionwindow-understand-how-merge-works), is that its applicable to Session Windows only and occurs on every event that can be merged with the previous window since every event for a Session Window create a new Window. I'm using PyFlink and would appreciate any help by providing an example.

Let's take an example that I put together from the documentation for the AverageAggregate function and some custom code:

```py
class MyTimestampAssigner(TimestampAssigner):
    def extract_timestamp(self, value, record_timestamp) -> int:
        return int(value[1])


class AverageAggregate(AggregateFunction):
 
    def create_accumulator(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        return 0, 0

    def add(self, value: Tuple[str, int], accumulator: Tuple[int, int]) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        return accumulator[0] + value[1], accumulator[1] + 1

    def get_result(self, accumulator: Tuple[int, int]) -> float:
        return accumulator[0] / accumulator[1]

    def merge(self, a: Tuple[int, int], b: Tuple[int, int]) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        return a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.set_parallelism(1)

    # define the source
    data_stream = env.from_collection([
        ('hi', 1), ('hi', 2), ('hi', 3), ('hi', 4), ('hi', 8), ('hi', 9), ('hi', 15)],
        type_info=Types.TUPLE([Types.STRING(), Types.INT()]))

    # define the watermark strategy
    watermark_strategy = WatermarkStrategy.for_monotonous_timestamps() \
        .with_timestamp_assigner(MyTimestampAssigner())

    ds = (
        data_stream
        .assign_timestamps_and_watermarks(watermark_strategy)
        .key_by(lambda x: x[0], key_type=Types.STRING())
        .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.with_gap(Time.milliseconds(3)))
        .aggregate(AverageAggregate())
    )

    # print the results
    ds.print()

    # submit for execution
    env.execute()
```

From my understanding, the `merge()` method should have run on the second event `('hi', 2)` since that is within the window size of 3 ms and then again for the input `('hi', 4)` and so on. But while executing the code, the `merge()` method doesn't even fire once. So if anyone can modify the sample code above to show `merge()` being executed and explain how it works would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a direct PyFlink example, you can have a look at the DataStream API recipe at https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/using-session-windows/#merging-data-in-one-session-window for info on the `merge()` method.

Disclaimer: I work for Immerok

Comment: thanks for the reply. I looked at the link you provided and it pretty much seems to confirm my understanding. So, given the [input data](https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/using-session-windows/#the-json-input-data), if you add another entry `{"id":6,"user":"Elvis Welch","timestamp":"2022-07-24T18:42:09.462994Z"}` (updated the timestamp and id), this should trigger the `merge()` method since the defined gap of 5 seconds has not passed yet and we already have a window for the key "Elvis Welch", right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct